# Sending position to .net server unity

Tags: unity, networking, client-server

I'm working on a multiplayer game, I created a custom C# server using TCPListner.

I can't figure out how to send a players position to the server from the client side. I also couldn't figure out how to broadcast the position received from the client side to the rest of the players. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can use TCPClient. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.80).aspx with a good example. You will send a message containing position to the server, and he will broadcast it to all client

Comment: This depends on what are building to.  TCP Client won't work for WebGL Builds.

Answer (score 1):

You should use TCPClient.
You must first set the tcpClient.

```
    _client = new TcpClient();
    if (_config == null || _config.Host == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    _client.Connect(_config.Host, _config.Port);
```

then you will be able to use it to send and receive packet.
Sending in asynchroneous way should be something like (in old fashion Async pattern while unity is still in 3.5)

```
       protected virtual void SendAsync(TrackingArgs p_args, object p_userState)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] l_array = ToByteArray(p_args);
                NetworkStream l_stream = _client.GetStream();
                AsyncInfo l_i = new AsyncInfo(p_args, l_array, l_stream, p_userState);
                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                IAsyncResult l_res = l_stream.BeginWrite(l_array, 0, l_array.Length, new AsyncCallback(WriteCallback), l_i);
            }
            catch (Exception l_e)
            {
                throw l_e;
            }
        }

        private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult p_ar)
        {
            AsyncInfo l_i = p_ar.AsyncState as AsyncInfo;
            Exception l_e = null ;
            try
            {
                l_i.stream.EndWrite(p_ar);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                l_i.stream.Close();
            }
            if (SendCompleted != null)
            {
                SendCompleted(this, new SendCompletedEventArgs(l_i.args, l_e, false, l_i.userState));
            }
        }
```

from this base, you can also write the ReceiveAsync method.
BTW, I do NOT check this code in Unity, this is only to give you a good starting point.

Have fun.

Comment: thx  guillaume ,
now i'm making the server in node js + socket io, i to much easy and less laggy :D